# Why page style being overriden by external CSS file?

Tags: html, css

I have main.css file where I define standard size for inputs:

```
/* Describe general input element sizes */
input[type="text"], input[type="password"]
{
    width: 180px;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
}
```

This CSS referred in header of the page. Later in page I define following:

```
<style>
        .shortField {
            width: 50px;
        }

    </style>
```

I assign class "shortField" to my input box but size is not applied. F12 screenshot:

[image]

Comment: didn't u try !important

Comment: !important is a hack-fix in this case. This should not be happening, from what I can see. Gotta think a tad longer.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. http://jsfiddle.net/4h7d4/

Comment: Juhana, I can't either, have no idea why..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to learn about specificity...

- The least specific stylesheet is what you link (External file)
- They styles you declared between document `head` tag is more specific than an external stylesheet
- And last but not the least, inline styles are MOST specific

And so in order to over ride, use `!important`(Don't use it if you don't know what it does and how it works) declaration or use more specific CSS selector like the one below

```
input[type=text].shortField {    /* This is more specific than simple element selector */
    /* Styles */ 
}
```

Comment: Your solution works, and I like it better than !important. I will mark as answer. But I still don't understand why.. I know about specificity. In my case I try to set same stile on page. I guess it's because I use class vs selector..

Comment: @katit Even styles are specific when it comes to selectors, for example simply writing `a { /* Styles here */ }` can be more specifically written as `a.class { /* Styles goes here */ }` or use a parent to select the child like `.parent_class a.class_name {}` or select a specific nth-child which will be even stronger like `.parent_class a.class:nth-of-type(1) {}`

Answer (score 3):

The [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity) of the first selector is `0-0-1-1`, the second selector's specificty is `0-0-1-0`, which means the first selector will override the second.

To override the initial selector, you only need to match the original specificity, as the second selector is later in the cascade.

The following selector should be enough to override the match with `input[type="text"]`, I've listed `.shortField` twice so that it will continue to match cases where it was used on non `input` elements.

```
.shortField,
input.shortField {
    width: 50px;
}
```

An alternative would be:

```
body .shortField {
    width: 50px;
}
```

Be very careful when raising the specificity of selectors. It's very easy to get into specificity games where you end up writing nonsensical styles like:

```
#foo #bar #baz #fizz #buzz .lorem .ipsum ul li a {
    margin-left: 0 !important;
}
```

Try to use the lowest specificty selectors that you possibly can.

Answer (score -1):

It is because the styles in your main.css file are more specific than in your html head.
If you really need to override it try doing this:

```
.shortfield {width: 50px !important;}
```

Answer (score -1):

Might help you to understand the hierarchy of importance for CSS.

```
Inline > Embedded > External
```

- Inline styles are anything within `style=""` and override any styles specified from embedded, or external stylesheets.
- Embedded styles are styles within `<style>` within the `<head>` of the document. They are overridden by inline, but override external.
- External styles are written in external files, and are overridden by either embedded or inline.

My theory is that you have styles overriding your external stylesheet.

Comment: There's no "theory" needed here, the first selector has a higher specificty than the second selector.